# Windows 10 universal app, Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in app.exe while accessing information of my device?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I am newbie to windows app development and C#. When I try to run this code from my app  it says

> unauthorized exception thrown

But Sample "MobileBroadband" app is executing same code smoothly on my Nokia 530

```
 try
 { 
     var modem = MobileBroadbandModem.GetDefault();
     IMEI = modem.DeviceInformation.MobileEquipmentId;
     MANUF = modem.DeviceInformation.Manufacturer;
     MODEL = modem.DeviceInformation.Model;
     Debug.WriteLine("Imei " + IMEI+" MANUF: "+MANUF+" MODEL: "+MODEL);
 } catch (Exception e) {
 }
```

Comment: I would suggest taking a look inside your solution, if you open the file "Package.appxmanifest" from visual studio you should see a tab "Capabilities". I'm not sure which one is the right option, so maybe try turning everything on and then running the app. If that works you can turn one at a time off until you find the appropriate one. Hope that helps. If it doesn't, let us know and we'll dig deeper :)

Comment: Yeah i tried by turning everything on. But as they told that only mobile operators can have that kind of access.

Answer (score 4):

I found it. To acquire these details app needs special permissions. And as i quote

"This functionality is only available to mobile operator apps and Windows Store apps given privileged access by mobile network operators. For more information, see  [Mobile Broadband: Windows Store device apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/Dn247051.aspx)."

Comment: This is the correct answer, additional reference material: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn391779.aspx  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270968.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check the Package.manifest file, and check if you set all the capabilities.

Comment: I think this should be a comment, because it certainly isn't an answer.

Comment: I think not, because he definetly hasn't set the manifest settings

Comment: You didn't say "The problem is your manifest file, and here's what you need to do to fix it". You said "I think you should check the manifest file", which is a suggestion. Answers are definitive; suggestions are not. You should edit it to make it an actual answer, or delete it and make it a comment to the question instead.

Comment: Ok Downvoted. Don't say I didn't give you a chance to change your post first.